# Do "The worstest" exist in english?

Tags: adjectives, comparative

I am wondering if the word "the worstest" exists in English? It seems like people sometimes use it.I have never found it in my English grammar book.

I am trying to find if it is a common mistake or a new word that gonna take part in English language someday.

Comment: Can you give us an example with a source?

Comment: Well I just sow some people use it on facebook (I know it mean nothing), and searching the word I found this [reference](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/worstest)

Comment: Native speakers sometimes intentionally use bad grammar as a form of humour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is used, probably as an informal  way to stress the meaning they want to suggest, but it is not grammatical.

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=worstest&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cworstest%3B%2Cc0):  worstest

> - ***I've just hadded the worstest actual news ever***. Hever. Pip and Merlin are moving. Not far. In actual very fact, just to the next village.
>     [Worzel Wooface – The quite very actual Terribibble Twos - Page 48](https://books.google.it/books?id=hF5lDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA48&dq=%22worstest%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijq_-ikYnfAhUPzKQKHaXtCFQQ6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q=%22worstest%22&f=false)
> - He struggles momentarily for words to express his performance and finally pronounces '***it was the worstest ever debut'.*** [White on Green: A Portrait of Pakistan Cricket](https://books.google.it/books?id=UumUCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT129&dq=%22worstest%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijq_-ikYnfAhUPzKQKHaXtCFQQ6AEINTAD#v=onepage&q=%22worstest%22&f=false)

[Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/worstest) defines its usage as nonstandard:

> ***Worstest:*** *(nonstandard) worst*, and provides a very old usage example:
>
> 1847, Thomas Preskett Prest, Varney the vampire; or, The feast of blood. [1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=worstest&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cworstest%3B%2Cc0)
>   - *Of all the blessed insults rolled into one, this here's the worstest.*

Comment: I remember in school quoting worzel gummage about his "bestest" head. I got a huge red mark.

Comment: I would add it usually to show uneducation in the speaker, Worsel being an excellent example, I know my kids do/did it a lot until they somehow learn which words you can add 'est' to and which you can't.